# How to wrap the content of a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have surfaceView class that is modeled after [this](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-iv,182.html), I populated it with 6 bitmaps. Is there a way to wrap the surfaceView around the bitmaps, instead of it covering the entire screen.

I have try this in my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.android.customclasses.Panel
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </com.android.customclasses.Panel>

</LinearLayout>
```

but this does not work. it just fill the parent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that SurfaceView has a notion of "wrap_content" (other than perhaps interpreting it to mean "fill_parent"). You would have to override `onMeasure` in your custom class `Panel` and call `setMeasuredDimension` with the appropriate size.

If you think about this it makes sense: your bitmaps are not inside the `SurfaceView` in the view hierarchy. They are simply being drawn by graphics commands to a `SurfaceView` which has a predetermined size.

Comment: Good answer. Which apps have you published on the market? I may buy if it is something I like :)

Comment: Thanks. I added some details to my user page. Nothing special! :p

Comment: I've got it! I wish if your app had a random mode, so that when I open it, I can read just one random paragraph. Good programmers know how good meditation brings good solutions :) Check for Lumis on the market you may find some happiness ;)